# how to remove newline characters in fasta sequence

Tags: linux, shell-script, awk, sed, newlines

I have fasta file (`modelfasta.fasta`) like this:

```
>seq1
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
GGGGGGGGGGG
>seq2
TTTTTTTTTTTTTTT
CCCCCCC
```

I am expecting output like this:

```
>header>seq1
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAGGGGGGGGGGG
>header>seq2
TTTTTTTTTTTTTTTCCCCCCC
```

I tried with sed and awk command with fasta  example file (modelfasta.fasta) but getting output in this way

```
awk '{printf $0""}' modelfasta.fasta 

>seq1AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAGGGGGGGGGGG>seq2TTTTTTTTTTTTTTTCCCCCCC
```

it removes newline just after header too and merges sequences with the header

the same result found with sed

```
sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n//g' modelfasta.fasta

>seq1AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAGGGGGGGGGGG>seq2TTTTTTTTTTTTTTTCCCCCCC
```

I want all the new lines removed except header's one, please help

Comment: Can you please format your code better. Not clear which is filename and which is content

Comment: the expected output has `>header` is that intentional ?

Answer (score 1):

You would like to remove all newlines from lines that do not start with the fasta header character `>`.

```
awk '/^[>;]/ { if (seq) { print seq }; seq=""; print } /^[^>;]/ { seq = seq $0 } END { print seq }' data.fa
```

The Awk script is

```
/^[>;]/    { if (seq) { print seq }; seq=""; print }
/^[^>;]/ { seq = seq $0 }
END     { print seq }
```

... which will do three different thing depending on what it finds in the file.

- A fasta header line (line starting with `>`), or a fasta comment line (line starting with `;`): Print any sequence that we have remembered in `seq` if there is any (this belongs to the previous header). Clear the remembered sequence. Print the current line (the header, or the comment).
- A fasta non-header (and non-comment) line: Concatenate the remembered sequence with the sequence on the line. This will effectively remove the newlines.
- The end of the file: Print the sequence. This is the sequence associated with the last header in the file.

If you'd want to do some pretty-printing of the sequence, for example limit it to 60 characters per line:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

function pretty(s) {
  p = "";
  n = 1;

  while (n < length(s)) {
    p = (p ? p "\n" : "") substr(s, n, 60);
    n += 60;
  }

  return p;
}

/^[>;]/  { if (seq) { print pretty(seq) }; seq=""; print }
/^[^>;]/ { seq = seq $0 } 
END      { print pretty(seq) }
```

Put that into `prettyfasta.awk` and make it executable (`chmod +x prettyfasta.awk`), then run it:

```
$ ./prettyfasta.awk data.fa
```

Comment: To also be able to have comments in the fasta file you may want tomodify the command a bit: `awk '/^[>;]/ { if (seq) { print seq }; seq=""; print } /^[^>;]/ { seq = seq $0 } END { print seq }'`

Comment: @Jaleks I've never ever seen that in use, but sure, the format allows it. I'll update my answer.